# Checking if variable is a Number in Puppet DSL

Tags: puppet

How to check that a variable is a Number in Puppet DSL ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the is_numeric function from the stdlib: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib